Is there a free version of Ohr Yakar online somewhere?
BH
Hi, I heard that Rav Moshe Cordovero wrote a comentary on the Zohar called Ohr Yakar. Does anyone know if there is a free version online somwhere like a pdf, or a transcription of it somewhere by any chance?

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8_(%D7%A8%D7%9E%22%D7%A7) ?
